# Split up Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, module

I've got a rather large Java EE web service application (100+ web services, 300k LOC, 500+ classes).  Even the small changes are difficult to get done mainly due to deployment process overhead: risk of taking down time, time to deploy a large application, risk of unintended changes due to building the whole application for one change, branch management, etc.  Currently deployed as a single EAR.

The application is already split out into service layer, business layer, DAOs, etc. but there is a pretty big dependency web across the classes, so no matter how you'd break it into parts there will be a lot of cross communication.

One option is breaking parts into JARs and deploying more exploded so JARs can be deployed independently.  The problem I think we'll have is compile dependencies across JARs so we'll get into a build mess, and likely class serialization issues if trying to drop new versions without a full recompile.

Another option is to break out into multiple WARs and do a bunch of RMI or webservice communication across the modules, but that's going to mean hundreds of new "internal" web services to manage, and likely increased response time.

Has anybody come across good solutions to the above?  Or tried something which is best to avoid?

Comment: Looks like you only organize your code in logical layers but not into physical ones (JARs, WARs, etc). So, you should use both approaches: split your giant project into several JARs and WARs accordingly.

Comment: At your scale, the overhead of learning and applying [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/HowOSGi) may be justified.